# ClamAV installation Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, clamav

I am trying to install ClamAV in ubuntu as per the instructions in

[blog.dutchcoders.io/installing-clamav-from-source/](http://blog.dutchcoders.io/installing-clamav-from-source/)

While updating the virus databases using

```
sudo freshclam -v
```

I am getting

```
Current working dir is /usr/local/share/clamav
Max retries == 3
ClamAV update process started at Mon Apr 11 13:10:34 2016
Using IPv6 aware code
Retrieving database.clamav.net/main.cvd
nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)
Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 219.94.128.99)
Ignoring mirror 219.94.128.99 (due to previous errors)
Trying host database.clamav.net (27.96.54.66)...
nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)
Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 27.96.54.66)
Trying host database.clamav.net (203.178.137.175)...
nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)
Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 203.178.137.175)
Trying host database.clamav.net (211.239.150.206)...
nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)
Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 211.239.150.206)
Trying host database.clamav.net (120.29.176.126)...
nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)
Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 120.29.176.126)
WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Mon Apr 11 13:13:09 2016
Using IPv6 aware code
Retrieving database.clamav.net/main.cvd
Ignoring mirror 120.29.176.126 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 211.239.150.206 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 27.96.54.66 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 203.178.137.175 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 219.94.128.99 (due to previous errors)
WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Mon Apr 11 13:13:15 2016
Using IPv6 aware code
Retrieving database.clamav.net/main.cvd
Ignoring mirror 27.96.54.66 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 211.239.150.206 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 120.29.176.126 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 219.94.128.99 (due to previous errors)
Ignoring mirror 203.178.137.175 (due to previous errors)
ERROR: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Giving up on database.clamav.net...
Update failed. Your network may be down or none of the mirrors listed in 
/usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf is working. Check http://www.clamav.net/doc/mirrors-faq.html for possible reasons.
```

Why is it so?? Is there any other way to resolve it??

I dont want ClamTK.

Comment: First option would be to try after sometime or you could use `sudo apt-get purge clamav-freshclam` and  
`sudo apt-get install clamav-freshclam`

Comment: He builded clamav from sources so apt-get wouldn't really help. Unless he is fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify:

- Have you checked your internet connection and firewall settings?
- Can you connect to the servers in question with wget or curl?
- Why do you build from sources?
- Have you tried the version you can install via apt-get?

Try these before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `freshclam.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/freshclam.conf
```

uncomment this line `#DNSDatabaseInfo current.cvd.clamav.net` (example):

```
 DNSDatabaseInfo current.cvd.clamav.net
```

After the line `#DatabaseMirror db.XY.clamav.net` add a new line like :

```
DatabaseMirror db.vn.clamav.net
```

You can replace `vn` by `us`,`fr`....

Make sur that `DatabaseMirror database.clamav.net` isn't commented.

Save and update

If you get an error try the following command:

```
chown -R 500:500 /var/lib/clamav
chmod -R 755 /var/lib/clamav
```